# How to generate an object that has all the Properties of another, only Nullable (when applicable)?

Tags: c#, class, reflection, dynamically-generated

I am creating a project that will manage app configurations. It will be very generic, reusable across different apps (with different config models on each) and very flexible - including the ability to create/save/store/read/merge partial configurations from multiple sources.

Without getting too much into details, here's an example of what I need to do.
I have a class like below:

```
public class TestConfigModel
{
    public int SomeIntValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeStringValue { get; set; }
    public TestConfigSubsection Subsection { get; set; }
}

public class TestConfigSubsection
{
    public System.DayOfWeek SomeSubsectionEnumValue { get; set; }
    public Guid SomeSubsectionGuidValue { get; set; }
}
```

I need to dynamically generate a version of this model that has all properties nullable (unless they already take a null):

```
public class TestConfigModelNullable
{
    public int? SomeIntValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeStringValue { get; set; } // already takes a null
    public TestConfigSubsection Subsection { get; set; } // already takes a null
}

public class TestConfigSubsectionNullable
{
    public System.DayOfWeek? SomeSubsectionEnumValue { get; set; }
    public Guid? SomeSubsectionGuidValue { get; set; }
}
```

Example use:

I have a default (complete) config like so:

```
var aConfigInstance = new TestConfigModel()
{
    SomeIntValue = 3,
    SomeStringValue = "hey",
    Subsection = new TestConfigSubsection()
    {
        SomeSubsectionEnumValue = DayOfWeek.Thursday,
        SomeSubsectionGuidValue = Guid.Parse("{2C475019-5AAC-43C6-AC87-21947A40E3B7}")
    }
};
```

Now, I need to be able to create, serialize, store and later deserialize and operate on a partial configuration model, like below:

```
var aPartialConfigInstance = new TestConfigModelNullable()
{
    SomeIntValue = 4,
    Subsection = new TestConfigSubsection()
    {
        SomeSubsectionEnumValue = DayOfWeek.Monday
    }
};
```

... with all missing properties null. If I try to do the same with the original class, all the other non-nullable fields will receive default values and that would be bad (how do I tell if int value of 0 is intended or not? Maybe it makes sense for the consumer app).

However, I'm new to reflection in general and not sure how to approach this. Your help would be much appreciated :)

Recall that we don't know the model ahead of time.

Comment: Generating types on the fly with Reflection.Emit is not a trivial task, I'm not convinced it's necessary here. What kind of serialization do you use? JSON? XML?

Comment: @felix-b - There are two sides of this coin ;) I intend to use Newtonsoft.Json, but I don't really want to depend too much on the serialization method used (it might also be something I want to inject when this is consumed). Also, I am really curious about doing this using reflection, so I would appreciate both simpler workarounds and a reflection approach :) Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you plan to write code that uses "nullable versions" of the models? Or you plan to specify partial configurations directly in JSON?

Comment: @felix-b - In my mind, I want to grab configurations from several sources: the (hardcoded, in-memory, complete) default from the consumer application, one (serialized, perhaps partial) from a global configuration file, one (serialized, perhaps partial) from a user's personal configuration file, another (serialized, perhaps partial) from a context-specific configuration file. Then, using some logic (which I indend to store as attributes on the configuration model in the consumer app), these different configs will be merged into a complete result model.

Comment: An example of this "merging logic": should a particular section of a "higher priority config" be taken if it's incomplete. This is for future backward-compatibility reasons. Let's say I have a functionality in the consumer app that now uses 5 settings and user creates a custom config for all 5. In next release of the app, the functionality has 7 settings. Question: should the incomplete user config be merged, filling in blanks with defaults, or should it be entirely discarded? The consumer app's developer will know that and will decorate the config model accordingly to indicate the merge logic

Comment: I guess I did not answer your question lol - I have a feeling that using nullable versions of the models (once I resolve creating them) will be an easier/more sound approach, than inspecting JSONs (assuming I wanted to stick with JSON, still unsure)

Comment: You can give T4 text templates a try. It is not easy, but better than falling back to Reflection.Emit API.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - I will, thanks. If you have a link to a good guide for my case, that'd be much appreciated ;)

Comment: MSDN has been influx for past 2-3 years with their history revisionist mindset. I'll try to find latest information and comment here if possible. P.S.: [Here you go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

I happened to implement several similar mechanisms in several different flavors. Implementing an "automagical" mechanism implies quite a bit of heavy lifting.

Here I wouldn't suggest generating separate nullable versions of the models. Instead, I would opt for making all model properties `Optional<T>`, which is like `Nullable<T>` but works for reference types as well. In this way, partial models will be represented with the same types as "base" models.

Such an approach will save the complexity of code generation (T4, Roslyn, CodeDom, or Reflection.Emit -- all these imply a lot of effort, including plugging them into the build process).

In addition, in either approach, a "merging" logic must be implemented which applies a partial model over a "base" one. In code generation approach, the merge logic can be generated as part of the nullable models. In `Optional<T>` approach, it can be either hard-coded or implemented in generic way with runtime Reflection (not Reflection.Emit). The hard-coded way appears to be the easiest, but for large number of models and properties, runtime Reflection may be a better fit.

#### How it will look

The models would look like this:

```cs
public class TestConfigModel
{
    public Optional<int> SomeIntValue { get; set; }
    public Optional<string> SomeStringValue { get; set; }
    public Optional<TestConfigSubsection> Subsection { get; set; }
}
```

With the implicit conversion operators of `Optional<T>`, you'll be able to initialize section values as normally:

```cs
var config = new TestConfigModel {
    SomeIntValue = 123,
    SomeStringValue = "ABC",
    Subsection = new TestConfigSubsection {
        SomeSubsectionEnumValue = DayOfWeek.Thursday
    }
};
```

Generic merging logic can be implemented by introducing an `Apply` method to `Optional<T>`:

```cs
Optional<T> Apply(Optional<T> partial, Func<T, T, Optional<T>> merge = null)
```

Every model will have to implement its own `ApplyXxxx()` method that will be passed in the `merge` parameter, like this:

```cs
public class TestConfigModel
{
    // ...properties

    public Optional<TestConfigModel> ApplyModel(TestConfigModel partial)
    {
        SomeIntValue = SomeIntValue.Apply(partial.SomeIntValue);
        SomeStringValue = SomeStringValue.Apply(partial.SomeStringValue);
        Subsection = Subsection.Apply(
            partial.Subsection, 
            merge: (left, right) => left.ApplySubsection(right)); 
        return this;
    }
}

public class TestConfigSubsection
{
    // ...properties

    public Optional<TestConfigSubsection> ApplySubsection(TestConfigSubsection partial)
    {
        SomeSubsectionEnumValue = SomeSubsectionEnumValue.Apply(partial.SomeSubsectionEnumValue);
        SomeSubsectionGuidValue = SomeSubsectionGuidValue.Apply(partial.SomeSubsectionGuidValue);
        return this;
    }
}
```

#### `Optional<T>`

Built-in implementation of `Optional<T>` is planned for C# 8, but it can be  implemented easily (mostly similar to `Nullable<T>`).

```cs
public interface IOptional
{
    bool HasValue { get; }
    object Value { get; }
}
public struct Optional<T> : IOptional
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;

    public Optional(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = true;
    }

    public bool HasValue => _hasValue;
    object IOptional.Value => Value;

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_hasValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("has no value");
            }
            return _value;
        }
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault() => _value;

    public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
    {
        if (!_hasValue)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        return _value;
    }

    public bool IsNullValue => _hasValue && ReferenceEquals(_value, null);

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is Optional<T> otherOptional)
        {
            if (_hasValue != otherOptional.HasValue)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (_hasValue)
            {
                return CompareValue(otherOptional.Value);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool CompareValue(object otherValue)
    {
        if (_value == null)
        {
            return (otherValue == null);
        }

        return _value.Equals(otherValue);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (_hasValue || ReferenceEquals(_value, null))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!_hasValue || ReferenceEquals(_value, null))
        {
            return "";
        }

        return _value.ToString();
    }

    public Optional<T> Apply(Optional<T> partial, Func<T, T, Optional<T>> merge = null)
    {
        if (!_hasValue && partial.HasValue)
        {
            return partial;
        }

        if (_hasValue && partial.HasValue)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_value, null))
            {
                return partial.Value;
            }

            if (!ReferenceEquals(partial.Value, null))
            {
                if (merge != null)
                {
                    return merge(_value, partial.Value);
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException("both values exist and merge not provided");
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    public static implicit operator Optional<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Optional<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Optional<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

#### Serialization

The last thing left is to teach the serializers to handle `Optional<T>`. For instance, Newtonsoft.Json would require a custom `JsonConverter`. Below isn't a complete implementation, but it demonstrates the approach:

```cs
public class OptionalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Optional<>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // TODO: implement properly
        // roughly the approach is like this:

        var hasValue = reader.ReadAsBoolean().GetValueOrDefault();
        var innerValue = hasValue 
            ? serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType.GetGenericArguments([0])
            : null;

        return Activator.CreateInstance(
            objectType, 
            innerValue != null ? new[] {innerValue} : new object[0]);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is IOptional optional)
        {
            // TODO: implement writing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this writeup, very detailed and helpful :). But I wish I could let the consumer determine their config model exactly as they want it. If integer is needed, model should have an int property. If a nullable integer is needed for business reason, then model should have an int? property. It would be great if using the merged config (result of my library's work) was as straightforward as using a static class full of static properties. Along the same line, forcing the base config model to use Optional<T>s forces extra markup (.Value) on every single call to it, a bit unwelcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just for convenience
public Type CreateNullableTypeFrom<T>()
{
  return CreateNullableTypeFrom(typeof(T));
}

public Type CreateNullableTypeFrom(Type typeToConvert)
{
  // Get the AssemblyName where the type is defined
  AssemblyName assembly = typeToConvert.Assembly.GetName();
  AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
  ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule(assembly.Name);
  TypeBuilder typeBuilder = dynamicModule.DefineType(typeToConvert.Name + "Nullable");

  // Loop through the properties
  foreach(PropertyInfo property in typeToConvert.GetProperties())
  {
    // If property is value type, it can't be null
    if(property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
    {
      // Create a nullable type for the property
      typeBuilder.DefineProperty(property.Name, property.Attributes, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType), Type.EmptyTypes);
    }
    // The property can be null
    else
    {
      // Create a similar property
      typeBuilder.DefineProperty(property.Name, property.Attributes, property.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
    }
  }

  // Finally, create the type
  Type convertedType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
  Console.WriteLine(convertedType.Name);
  // Note: to access the properties of the converted type through reflection,
  //       use GetRuntimeProperties method, not GetProperties, since GetProperties
  //       will return an empty array because the type was created an runtime

  return convertedType;
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you make an example how someone can make a Nullable type with your code?